# English translation of M.-F. Vigneras "Arithmétique des algèbres de quaternions"

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, quaternions

I am looking to understand a citation about the connection of quaternion algebra over number fields which when embedded into $\mathbb{C}$, leads to a discrete subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ which causes tilings of the hyperbolic 3-manifold $\mathbb{H}^3$. The author mentions the chapter 4 in the French book M.-F. Vigneras -"Arithmétique des algèbres de quaternions" for some computations of the fundamental volume of this tiling, but due to my loose knowledge of French, I cannot understand this text.

If you can tell me about an English translation of this text or if you can give me a reference that provides the same material in English, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Did you try John Voight's book in progress https://math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/quat.html ?

Comment: In addition to any other answers, it is fair to say that you should probably learn to read mathematical French.  (This is unavoidable for me as a representation theorist, but I imagine it's true in many disciplines.)  It's way easier to learn the mathematical version than even the most basic conversational version of the language.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger
Thank you! It seems to be a useful reference.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for the suggestion. I am in the pursuit of learning French and your suggestion certainly motivates me.

Comment: https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/7921447/the-arithmetic-of-quaternion-algebra

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer Thanks! That is perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be an English translation of Vigneras book. If not, at least there is [Arithmetic of Hyperbolic 3-manifolds](http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9780387983868) by Colin McLachlan and Alan Reid.  That book has information about quaternion algebras.

I'll look into discussion of the fundamental volume of the tiling over $\mathbb{H}^3$.

In Chapter 11 they discuss [Tamagawa measure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111339/simple-tamagawa-number-calculations).  If $A$ is a quaternion algebra,  and $\mathcal{O} \subseteq A $ is a maximal order then we've got a formula for the volume:

$$\text{Vol}\big( SL(2,\mathbb{C})  / \rho (\mathcal{O}  ) \big)=
\frac{|\Delta_k|^{3/2}\zeta_k(2)\prod_{\mathcal{P}\big|N(A)}\big( N(\mathcal{P})-1\big)}
{(4\pi^2)^{[k:\mathbb{Q}]-2}}$$

This volume is expressed in terms of invariants of the quaternion algebra,  which are in the textbook.  For example $k/\mathbb{Q}$ is the number field which was used to define $A$, and $\zeta_k(2)$ is the Zeta function.  There's another formula for  volumes of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})   $ quotients as well.

Comment: This is not my specialty.  I am using this answer as learning opportunity.  Also interested in the use of $\zeta_F (2)$ for number fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. That was certainly helpful.